# Static files not working in Django

Tags: django, static-files, django-statistics

My static files were absolutely working fine, but yesterday I tried using the app allauth and since then my static files are not being displayed. It is not showing any css or js. I tried commenting the allauth app and even then it does not work.

However I just figured out the problem. Django is appending the wrong path to the static files. It should be /static/style.css but it is searching it at /"module-name"/style.css What could be the possible reason. I have correctly configured the static files path in the settings.py file as
STATIC_URL = "/static"

Comment: sounds like something may be overriding your settings. You could try doing a search via grep for "module-name" in your project directory and see if there is a default somewhere that is messing with what you want.

Comment: Thanks... but for the time being I have removed that app and its working fine...

Comment: well when/if you want to get that app working, post the relevant parts of your settings file so that people can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allauth prescribes using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS like this::

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   ...
    "allauth.context_processors.allauth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account"
)
```

Here, the dots refer to whatever context processors you were using before. If you did not have any, you were implicitly using the Django defaults specified over here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-context-processors

So I suspect your problem will go away when you insert the defaults where the dots are. Correct?