# Django AllAuth static files not showing up

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-allauth

I am trying to install [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but after installing the app, authentication backends, and context processors django is no longer able to find my files.

And before this is marked as a dupe, I DO have all of the default context processors listed. This was the problem in these two questions:

[Static files not working in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399897/static-files-not-working-in-django)

[Django not able to find the static files when using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445429/django-not-able-to-find-the-static-files-when-using-django-allauth)

Some settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (                                                                                            
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',                                                                         
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',                                                                                
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',                                                                                 
    'django.core.context_processors.media',                                                                                
    'django.core.context_processors.static',                                                                               
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',                                                                                   
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',                                                                 
    'django.core.context_processors.request',                                                                              
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',                                                                          
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',                                                              
)                                                                                                                          

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (                                                                                                
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',                                                                           
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',                                                                 
)  


INSTALLED_APPS = (                                                                                                         
    'django.contrib.auth',                                                                                                 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',                                                                                         
    'django.contrib.sessions',                                                                                             
    'django.contrib.sites',                                                                                                
    'django.contrib.messages',                                                                                             
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',                                                                                          
    'grappelli',                                                                                                           
    'django.contrib.admin',                                                                                                
    'django.contrib.admindocs',                                                                                            
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',                                                                                             
    'django.contrib.flatpages',                                                                                            

    # 3rd party                                                                                                            
    'compressor',                                                                                                          
    'debug_toolbar',                                                                                                       
    'filebrowser',                                                                                                         
    'mongo',                                                                                                               
    'south',                                                                                                               
    'sysmon',                                                                                                              
    'rest_framework',                                                                                                      

    'allauth',                                                                                                             
    'allauth.account',                                                                                                     
    'allauth.socialaccount',                                                                                               
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',                                                                            

    # Apps                                                                                                                 
    'my_app',                                                                                                           
)
```

As you can see I've included all the default context processors so I'm not simply overriding the context processor tuple. Does the order matter of the context processors, or for my installed apps? All my static files were working beforehand, they don't load when I add django-allauth and run the server with `./manage.py runserver`.

I'm using Django 1.4.6

Comment: Oh my god, it worked. I should have asked sooner. Thanks man! If you post it as a solution I'll give you credit instead of answering my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `allauth*` apps to the end of `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.